# OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature, strange behavior

Tags: openlayers-2

I've been reading in this forum for a while and it helps me lot of times. Now I think it is the time to help me again but maybe other people too. So I try to describe a problem I have with OpenLayers 2.13 dev and the drag feature control.

First of all. I'm working on a bigger GIS Application and the most libraries are bound to this. So I can't change them.

**The Problem:**

```
//=>layer for the control was created correctly (controlled with firebug)
var dragCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(editLayer);
app.mapPanel.map.addControl(dragCtrl);
dragCtrl.activate();
//=>if i use console.log at this time I can see the control was created correctly and
//looks like any other drag control on the map


//=>Just for explanation: the record element is from a geoext feature store
var lonlat = record.data.feature.geometry.bounds.getCenterLonLat();
var xy = lonlat.toShortString();
var xyArray = xy.split(', ')

var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(xyArray[0],xyArray[1]);

var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
editLayer.addFeatures(feature);
//=>at this time I expect that it should be possible to drag the added feature on the
//layer
```

The snippet of code is used in a listener which is executed each time I select a row in a table where some features are stored. So each time there will be a new element of `OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature`. This is only for testing. Now the strange thing. The first time I call this snippet above I can't drag the feature on the layer. Even if I zoom the map and redraw the layer.

But if I call the code again the new control is added to the map (I have now 2 new dragcontrols at the map => firebug) and a new feature on the layer the drag control works like a charm. For every feature. Also if I call it again and again (new control each time).

It doesn't matter where I create the control and where I add it (also if I creates it only one time at the init of the application). If I have only one control on the layer it doesn't work. Each new one works.

Only the first time it fails. What is the problem here?

It is a simple piece of code I think. But I banging my head for it about one week without any solution. I really hope that the solution is simple and I just missed a little detail. Maybe there is anybody out there who had the same problem?!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had an active select control on another layer.
You need to .deactivate() any select controls in order for the drag control to work.

```
      //deactivate control on layer 1:
      this.selectControlOnLayer1.deactivate();

      //activate Layer2 control:
      this.dragControlOnLayer2.activate();

      // and vice-versa to go back to select controls.
```

this seemed relevant, from [the Openlayers Documentation](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html) :

> "The activate call will move the vector layer to the forefront of the
>   map, so that all events will occur on this layer.
>
> As of OpenLayers 2.7, there is no support for selecting features from
>   more than a single vector layer at a time. The layer which is
>   currently being used for selection is the last one on which the
>   .activate() method of the attached select feature control was called."